# Building an exact match based on string

Tags: go, couchbase, go-gin

I am using Couchbase 5.1.1 with Go Lang 1.11 and trying to remove results based on is value, its exact value.

Now I have this working with another field, which is an ID and that matches up fine and is all working but the data being returns has a status of "Available" and "Not Available". I am trying to remove all the data has is set to "Not Available" status.

So this is what I have setup and added the ID check to,

```
qp := cbft.NewConjunctionQuery()

qp.And(cbft.NewConjunctionQuery( cbft.NewMatchQuery(ID).Field("ID") ))
```

This is what I have done to return only the available data,

```
qp.And(cbft.NewConjunctionQuery( cbft.NewMatchQuery("Available").Field("status") ))
```

However, its not doing an exact match, it removes other data (there is like 6 or so statuses) but not anything with the word "Available" in it, so its still returning "Not Available" data.

I have tried using, `NewMatchPhraseQuery`, as well as adding a `.Fuzziness(0)` to the `NewMatchQuery`. But nothing is working.

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you're doing exact matches, why not use a N1QL query instead?

Comment: There are a number of GET string inputs all setup to filter this data. This option has to be added to these queries. Can I mix a N1QL and FTS search?

Comment: "There are a number of GET string inputs all setup to filter this data" - I don't know what that means, maybe it's a Go thing. "Can I mix a N1QL and FTS search?" Maybe with CURL inside of N1QL, or you can match results up in your code using document keys. But before going down that route, I guess I'd need more detail as to why you must use FTS for an exact match.

Comment: The API is setup to take a users request via GET strings to filter the data, e.g. maxPrice or minPrice. There are a number of these options all added to query each from different users / clients which will all request different types of data. This is all setup to use a FTS. I just need the final output of these data to remove all data based on the status I want to set.

Comment: I have asked another question, which is like this but reserves the logic. I want to add all the data based on what I want to set, if it was not set then dont include it. I have asked at, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52627237/how-to-exclude-data if I can do a sort of where not type query on an FTS index. So it would return all the data apart from the 'not available'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Couchbase exact value match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52610544/couchbase-exact-value-match)