# Couchbase exact value match

Tags: go, couchbase

I am using **Couchbase 5** and **Go Lang 1.11**, trying to query results based on an exact value.

The code below is finding rows with a status of "Available" and "Not Available". How can I make it only return "Available" rows?

```
qp.And(cbft.NewConjunctionQuery( cbft.NewMatchQuery("Available").Field("status") ))
```

Comment: If you're doing exact matches, why not use a N1QL query instead?

Comment: @MatthewGroves What's an example of that?

Comment: A simple example is: `SELECT d.* FROM myDocuments d WHERE status = 'Available'`

Answer (score 2):

It will depend on how you analyze the input field, it would help to know what analyzer you are using, but I'll assume the default, "standard", analyzer for now.

Don't use the default analyzer for this case. As Matt asked in his comment, you are trying to do a direct match of exact text in a phrase, which is a little different than most text search users. So you don't really want the text to be tokenized into smaller pieces.

Create a custom analyzer with the Couchbase search GUI that uses the "single" [tokenizer](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/5.5/fts/fts-using-analyzers.html#tokenizers) so that all the text in the field will be kept together. Or you could just **use the "keyword" analyzer** which is probably close enough for you.  Set that as your default analyzer and your query should work as expected.

If you are looking for another approach, then a [term or term phrase query](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/5.5/fts/fts-query-types.html#non-analytic-queries) may be more what you are after, but you'll still have to be conscious of how analyzers are working.

[image: Set default analyzer for Couchbase full-text search analyzer to use "keyword"]